# JAGS compilation error

Tags: compiler-errors, jags

My seemingly straightforward model keeps giving me strange compilation errors.

> Runtime Error:
>   Compilation error on line 17.
>   Unknown variable Nx
>   Either supply values for this variable with the data or define it  on the left hand side of a relation.

Here is my code:

```
dataList = list(
  x = x ,
  y = y ,
  xP = xProbe
)

Here's the JAGS model:  
1    data{  
2        Ntotal <- length(y)  
3        ym <- mean(y)  
4        ysd <- sd(y)  
5        for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {  
6          zy[i] <- ( y[i] - ym ) / ysd  
7        }  
8        Nx <- length(xName)  
9        for ( j in 1:Nx ) {  
10         xm[j]  <- mean(x[,j])  
11         xsd[j] <-   sd(x[,j])  
12         for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {  
13           zx[i,j] <- ( x[i,j] - xm[j] ) / xsd[j]  
14         }  
15       }  
16       Nprobe <- Ntotal  
17       for ( j in 1:Nx ) {  
18         xPm[j]  <- mean(xP[,j])  
19         xPsd[j] <-   sd(xP[,j])  
20         for (i in 1:Nprobe ) {  
21           zxP[i,j] <- ( xP[i,j] - xPm[j] ) / xPsd[j]  
22         }  
23       }  
24   }  
25   model{  
26       for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {  
27         zy[i] ~ dt( zbeta0 + sum(zbeta[1:Nx]*zx[i,1:Nx]), 1/zsigma^2, nu)  
28       }  
29      # Priors vague on standardized scale:  
30       zbeta0 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/2^2 )     
31       for ( j in 1:Nx ) {  
32         zbeta[j] ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/2^2 )  
33       }  
34       zsigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-5 , 1.0E+1 )  
35       nu ~ dexp(1/30.0)  
36      # Transform to original scale:  
37       beta[1:Nx] <- ( zbeta[1:Nx] / xsd[1:Nx] )*ysd  
38       beta0 <- zbeta0* ysd + ym - sum(zbeta[1:Nx]*xm[1:Nx]/xsd[1:Nx])*ysd  
39       sigma <- zsigma*ysd  
40      # Predicted y values as xProbe:  
41       for ( i in 1:Nprobe ) {  
42         zyP[i] ~ dt(zbeta0+sum(zbeta[1:Nx]*zxP[i,1:Nx]),1/zsigma^2, nu)  
43         yP[i] <- zyP[i] * ysd + ym  
44       }  
45   }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you have not defined what `xName` is on line 8, which `Nx` is dependent on.  Define that in the `dataList` and you should be good to go (in regards to fixing this single error).

Comment: I just wonder why JAGS has not given the same error on line 9 first.

Comment: JAGS does not run through scripts line by line, and loops are not done sequentially.

Comment: Yeah, the formatting of the list and the communication between R and jags can be rather confusing if you are used to R!!! I would suggest you accept @mfidino s answer!